# Laplace transform and Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, laplace-transform, fourier-transform

**I used the Fourier and Laplace transforms to solve a series of equations. Now I have to use the inverse of these conversions to get the wave function. My question is**
$$L^{-1}(\frac{d}{dk}\psi(k,s))=?\frac{d}{dk}\psi(k,t)$$
$$F({\frac{d}{dx}\psi})=-ik\psi(k)$$ $$F^{-1}({\frac{d}{dk}\psi(k)})=?-ix\psi(x)$$

Comment: Integrate your equations in $k$ over an interval, and see if you can verify the resulting equations in integrated form. Then see if you can differentiate with respect to the upper limit $k$. That's usually much easier than trying to deal with the derivative expressions.

Comment: Are written relationships correct?